Time series predictions using python GEKKO
This a follow up question to this one: Predictions using python GEKKO
I'm trying to create an ARX model to be able to model rotations on a masonry wall using past observations and temperatures measured.
This code uses gekko 1.0.7
Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PJJVZPCJRSECAyzoAl-8TWDZSKf6jwSl/view?usp=sharing
Firstly I indentified my model using m.sysid() using order 10 for endogs and exogs
t = df_c3_avg5_c2['Tempo'].iloc[465:829]
u = df_c3_avg5_c2[['STH-04','STH3_avg']].iloc[465:829]
y = df_c3_avg5_c2['C14-Y'].iloc[465:829]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

na = 10 
nb = 10 
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,pred='meas')


I find it strange that the model fitted almost never follows the data and besides that it roughly seems to be generating local max values where local mins should be and the other way around.
After that I try and use the model created to a test subset of data to evaluate it's performance.
tm = df_c3_avg5_c2['Tempo'].iloc[829:904]
um = df_c3_avg5_c2['STH-04'].iloc[829:904]
ym = df_c3_avg5_c2['C14-Y'].iloc[829:904]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

y,u = m.arx(p)
y[0].value = ym[0]

m.time = tm
u[0].value = um

m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes = 2

m.solve(disp=False)


Here I am not able to use again two inputs so, as written in the code above these refer to using only temperatures from STH-04. Here the fitting is not being done right, instantly in the beggining there's a sudden variation that I cannot understand where it comes from.

Could you make the data link shareable or post the complete data set in the question?

@JohnHedengren done, sorry for the hassle
